# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission file read)

Tags: java, security, applet

Below code prompts for the input box for the file name and location.
When I enter `file://C:/test/abc.tiff` then I am getting

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission \\c\test\abc.tiff read)
```

Code Snippet

```
CMBDocument document = evt.getDocument();
    String docSaveFileName = (String) docToURL.get(document);
     System.out.println("docSaveFileName :"+docSaveFileName);
            docSaveFileName = docSaveFileName.replaceAll("servlet", "annotate");
            System.out.println("modified docSaveFileName :"+docSaveFileName);
            File tempFile = null;
            try {
                if (evt.getSaveAsNew() || document.isModified()) {
                    if (evt.getSaveAsNew()) {
                        docSaveFileName =
                            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(myGenDocViewer,
                                "Enter the name of the file to save the document:");
                    }
                    if (docSaveFileName == null) { // user cancelled
                        return;
                    }

                    currStreamingDocServices.setPreferredFormats(
                        new String[] { document.getMimeType()});

                    if (document.getCanWrite()) {
                        URL url = new URL(docSaveFileName);
                        OutputStream out = null;
                        String protocol = url.getProtocol();
                        String host = url.getHost();
                        // Use FileOutputStream if this URI is for a local file.
                        if (protocol.equals("file") 
                            && (host == null || host.length() == 0 || host.equals("localhost"))) {
                            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(url.getPath()));
                        }

                        else {
                            URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
                            urlCon.setDoInput(false);
                            urlCon.setDoOutput(true);
                            urlCon.setUseCaches(false); // Enable tunneling.
                            if (urlCon instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                                HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) urlCon;
                                httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                            }
                            urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-type",document.getWriteMimeType());
                            out = urlCon.getOutputStream();
                        }
                        document.write(out);
                        out.close();
                        document.setModified(false);
                        document.setNew(false);
                        myGenDocViewer.setDocName(document, docSaveFileName);
```

Comment: The path in the error message does not match the path you give as a parameter.

Comment: @KurtDuBois Sorry,the error msg is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission \\c\test\abc.tiff read)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of application are you using this code from? If it's an applet, you're touching a sandboxing problem: applets cannot read or write files on the file system.

Comment: Yes ,it is applet. I tried to set security policy i.e. " -Djava.security.policy=all.policy"

Comment: You could try working around it by signing the jar-file containing your applet (http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html), but that also has its limitations.

Comment: Can I do this without signing jar file??

Comment: No, as I said: you're running into a sandboxing problem of applets. The JVM will not allow your applet to read or write files on the local filesystem of the computer on which the applet is executed.

Comment: *"No, .. you're running into a sandboxing problem of applets."*  That can be avoided in newer JREs.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do this without signing jar file?

Sure thing.  The plug-in 2 JRE allows us to access the local file-system from a sand-boxed applet, using the JNLP API services.  Here is a [demo. of the file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

That demo. is of a free-floating application, but for the same in an applet (without source code), see [GIFanim](http://pscode.org/gifanim/#applet).

Comment: I tried with jnlp but getting exception.Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663215/unable-to-save-applet-using-jnlp